# Chain of responsibility special scenario

Tags: java, design-patterns, chain-of-responsibility

In normal chain of responsibility design pattern implementation, handlers of the request will be added to the chain in a sequential order and will be executed accordingly. However in a special scenario if it's required to skip intermediate handlers and process request in the final handler, will it violate COR design pattern?
Please refer the code snippets below. Hope it will clarify this further.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class SomeHandler extends RequestProcessor {

public SomeHandler() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void process(Request request) {
    if (request != null) {
        //Logic to decide request type
        if ("TYPE_ONE".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getType())) {
            //passing to next object in the chain. Multiple chains...
            this.nextRequestProcessor.process(request);
        } else if ("TYPE_TWO".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getType())) {
            //passing to the last object in the chain,skip all the other intermediate objects
            new FinalHandler().process(request);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: something you could also consider is using a priority system (i.e. all handlers of the same highest priority are handled first etc.). Probably a bit overkill if you only have one handler that's highest priority though. I'm not to sure how this effects the design pattern however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit subjective.

This handler knows that a certain type of request must be handled by a certain handler<sup>1</sup>. So, it bypasses the chain and invokes the handler directly. This means that this handler is aware of other (concrete) handlers in the chain (a leak of knowledge).

Note: Rather than creating a new instance of the handler, you could have had a reference to the final handler instance in `SomeHandler`.

Alternatively, you can make this decision before invoking the chain.

```
public class Client {
    private RequestProcessor chainOfRequestProcessors;
    private RequestProcessor finalHandler; //instance of FinalHandler

    public void process(Request request) {
        if ("TYPE_TWO".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getType())) {
            finalHandler.process(request);
        } else {
            //handle normally
            chainOfRequestProcessors.process(request);
        }
    }
}
```

A design pattern is just that. A pattern or a skeletal template for a solution to solve a particular type of problem. It doesn't mean you cannot *tweak* it and use it in a different way as per your use-case or need (given that you know what you are doing).

---

<sup>1</sup>
You've said ([emphasis mine])

> .... However in a **special scenario** if it's required to skip intermediate handlers and process request in the final handler ...

But in your example, the delegation happens in an usual way (by checking the request type). It appears that, in this example, you can simply keep delegating if none of the intermediate handlers can process request type `TYPE_TWO`. But I guess there is something more to determine when we should go straight to the last handler and the example has been simplified.

Comment: Here SomeHandler is not the first handler. When the execution has come to the SomeHandler that means chain has already invoked. But if I understood you correctly I can still pass the request to the other handlers and can decide weather to apply handler logic based on the request status (in this specific case type of the request ). And all type of requests can be processed in the final handler. This way there is no interruption to the chain execution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: *I can still pass the request to the other handlers[...] and all type of requests can be processed in the final handler.* - Not sure I understand this part and your special scenario. Is there an intermediate handler capable of handling a request, but you don't want it to handle for 'some case'? Or do you want it to handle plus the request be handled by the last handler?

Comment: If it is the former, you should skip delegating to it or it should be aware that it shouldn't handle a request when some condition holds. If it is the latter, then I think after handling, it can still call the other handlers in the chain till it reaches the last handler.

Comment: Once the request type is decided, and it is request type two, basically it should only execute the logic in the final handler. And for all the other requests it should come to final handler via all handlers.

Comment: What if you normally go through the chain? Is there an intermediate handler which handles request type two (which you are looking to skip for some reason)?

Comment: If I normally go through there is no technical problem. But functionally we don’t need to treat the request type two as we do for other types. It is kind of a resource waste as we have few api call’s related to other requests. As of now there is no specific handler to handle type two.

Comment: Did you measure your performance? If your concern is just the delegations among a few handlers (`h1 -> h2 -> h3 ... finalHandler`), it is not something to be worried about.